# Efficient picture frame matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of pictures, each with a certain width and height.  I also have a set of frames, each with a certain width and height.

A picture can be put in a frame if the frame width and height is greater than the picture width and height (the pictures and frames cannot be rotated)

What is an efficient algorithm that **minimizes the number of empty picture frames**?

(It can be assumed that the number of pictures are greater than the number of frames)

PS:: If someone could point me to the correct name of this problem, that'd be great

Answer (score 0):

It a type of combinatorial optimization problem. Despite the simple description, this is quite an interesting problem and not a trivial one. It's interesting because to solve it one needs to optimize in two dimensions, but they are not independent dimensions.

In other words, we could pick one dimension, say width, and then easily optimize for that dimension simply ordering the frames by width and then selecting the widest picture less than each frame. But doing so could make the fitting highly non-optimal in the height dimension.

The way to solve this type of problem in general is to find a way to optimize sub units, that is subsets of frames, that can all be filled, and then build up each of these subsets progressively until you find the largest subset that has pictures in all of it. The technique to do this in software is called [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way to solve it, but treating it as a maximum bipartite matching https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs is at least polynomial. The vertices represent pictures or frames, and there is an edge between a picture and a frame if that picture will fit in that frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem): you are assigning pictures to frames. Each assignment has a cost: a picture assigned to a smaller frame has a positive cost (e.g. 1) and a picture assigned to a too large frame has an infinitely small cost. And you try to maximise the total cost (e.g. you try to assign as many pictures to frames as possible; which is the same a minimising the number of empty frames). This can be solved using linear programming.

Below I give an example in R, using the `lpSolve` package. It uses a function `match_n_to_m` which is defined [here](https://github.com/djvanderlaan/reclin/blob/master/R/match_n_to_m.R), but I also have given the definition below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lpSolve)

# Some sample data
pictures <- read.csv(textConnection("id,pwidth,pheight
1,20,30
2,10,30
3,20,40
4,50,90
6,10,10"))

frames <- read.csv(textConnection("id,fwidth,fheight
1,40,90
2,10,10
3,11,11
4,5,5"))

# Generate every possible (valid = picture fits in frame) pair
pairs <- expand.grid(frame = frames$id, picture = pictures$id) %>%
  left_join(frames, c("frame" = "id")) %>%
  left_join(pictures, c("picture" = "id")) %>% 
  filter(pwidth >= fwidth, pheight >= fheight)

# Each picture can only be assigned to one frame and each frame can only contain
# one picture. Try to assign as many pictures as possible.
selection <- match_n_to_m(pairs$frame, pairs$picture, w = rep(1, nrow(pairs)))
pairs[selection, ]
```

Result:

```
#    frame picture fwidth fheight pwidth pheight
# 1      2       1     10      10     20      30
# 7      3       3     11      11     20      40
# 9      1       4     40      90     50      90
# 14     4       6      5       5     10      10
```

Definition of `match_n_to_m`:

```
#' Force n to m matching on a set of pairs
#' 
#' @param x a vector of identifiers for each x in each pair This vector should 
#'   have a unique value for each element in x.
#' @param y a vector of identifiers for each y in each pair This vector should 
#'   have a unique value for each element in y.
#' @param w a vector with weights for each pair. The algorithm will try to 
#'   maximise the total weight of the selected pairs. 
#' @param n an integer. Each element of x can be linked to at most n elements of
#'   y. 
#' @param m an integer. Each element of y can be linked to at most m elements of
#'   y. 
#'
#' @details
#' The algorithm will try to select pairs in such a way each element of \code{x}
#' is matched to at most \code{n} elements of \code{y} and that each element of
#' \code{y} is matched at most \code{m} elements of \code{x}. It tries to select 
#' elements in such a way that the total weight \code{w} of the selected 
#' elements is maximised. 
#' 
#' @examples
#' d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3), y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), w=1:7)
#' # One-to-one matching:
#' d[match_n_to_m(d$x, d$y, d$w), ]
#' 
#' # N-to-one matching:
#' d[match_n_to_m(d$x, d$y, d$w, n=999), ]
#' 
#' # One-to-m matching:
#' d[match_n_to_m(d$x, d$y, d$w, m=999), ]
#' 
#' # N-to-M matching, e.g. select all pairs
#' d[match_n_to_m(d$x, d$y, d$w, n=999, m=999), ]
#' 
#' @export
match_n_to_m <- function(x, y, w, n = 1, m = 1) {
  if (!requireNamespace("lpSolve", quietly=TRUE)) 
    stop("You need the lpSolve package to use this function.")
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(w))
  stopifnot(length(n) == 1 && as.integer(n) == n)
  stopifnot(length(m) == 1 && as.integer(m) == m)
  stopifnot(!(anyNA(x) || anyNA(y) || anyNA(w)))
  if (length(x) == 0) return(integer(0))

  d  <- data.frame(x=as.numeric(as.factor(x)), y=as.numeric(as.factor(y)), w=w)
  nx <- length(unique(d$x))
  ny <- length(unique(d$y))
  C  <- cbind(c(d$x, d$y + nx), seq_len(nrow(d)))
  C  <- cbind(C, 1)
  res <- lpSolve::lp("max", d$w, dense.const = C, const.dir = rep("<=", nx+ny), 
    const.rhs = c(rep(n, nx), rep(m, ny)), all.bin=TRUE, use.rw=TRUE)  
  if (res$status != 0) warning("No solution found.")
  which(res$solution > 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here invoke unnecessarily complicated machinery; you don't need any sophisticated algorithms that can only be referred to, not even summarized, in a Stack Overflow answer.

Rather, you can use a fairly straightforward "greedy" approach, where you iterate over the pictures, taking the "best" frame for each one. Of course, you need to iterate over the pictures in the right order, and you need to correctly identify the "best" frame for each one; but that turns out to be pretty simple:

- Iterate over the pictures from widest to narrowest.
- For each picture, choose the shortest as-yet-unchosen frame that's both wider and taller (if any exist).

You can do this in *O*(*p* log *f*) time, where *p* is the number of pictures and *f* is the number of frames (using your assumption that *f* < *p*).

---

To understand this approach, let's start by considering the one-dimensional case, where we're fitting sticks of varying lengths into slots of varying lengths. We want a solution where we iterate over the sticks and select the "best" slot for each one. The key insight is that there are *two* such solutions:

- Solution A: if we iterate over the sticks in order from longest to shortest, then we can choose *any* as-yet-unchosen slot that's long enough for a given stick, because all such slots are "equivalent" in that they're equally good for all remaining sticks.
- Solution B: if we iterate over the sticks in an arbitrary order, then we can choose the *shortest* as-yet-unchosen slot that's long enough for a given stick, because choosing a longer slot won't help, and might restrict our future options.

(In both cases, I'm taking advantage of the fact that we don't have any preferences among the sticks or the slots; we just want to maximize the total number of sticks that end up in slots. So it's never better to leave a given stick unslotted; if it fits in any slots at all, then it might as well go in one.)

In the two-dimensional case, with pictures and frames instead of sticks and slots, we use Solution A for the "width" dimension (iterate over the pictures from widest to narrowest), and Solution B for the "height" dimension (for each picture, select the shortest eligible frame). This works because the two solutions are, in a sense, "compatible": Solution A doesn't care which frame we select for a given picture (so Solution B can do what it wants without interference), and Solution B doesn't care which picture we select a frame for (so Solution A can do what it wants without interference).

(Unfortunately, this means that my solution only works for the two-dimensional case; I don't think it can be extended to three dimensions.)

---

To actually implement this in *O*(*p* log *p*) time, do the following:

- Sort the list of frames by width. You can do this in *O*(*f* log *f*) time.
- Sort the list of pictures by width. You can do this in *O*(*p* log *p*) time.
- Initialize an empty red-black tree (or similar) to hold frames in order by height.
- Iterate over the pictures from widest to narrowest. For each picture:

  - Move any frames that are wider than the picture (starting at the "wide" end of the list of frames) to the red-black tree. Since each frame is moved at most once, and the red-black tree never holds more than *f* frames, this adds up to *O*(*f* log *f*) time over the course of the algorithm.
  - Find and remove the shortest frame in the red-black tree that is taller than the picture (if any). This can be done in *O*(log *f*) time for each picture.

To improve this to *O*(*p* log *f*) time, observe that two pictures essentially have equivalent width if there's no frame whose width distinguishes them. (For example, if two pictures have widths 37.1 and 38.2, then their widths are equivalent unless there's a frame whose width is in the range (37.1, 38.2].) So instead of *fully* sorting the pictures, we can create an array of *f* "buckets" of pictures of different width-ranges (up to the width of the largest frame: we can discard any pictures wider than that). We can then place each picture into the right bucket using binary search, which is *O*(log *f*) for each picture.